# Plot predictions for a poisson model with reference value = 0

Tags: r, prediction

The `Predict` function of the `rms` package in R has an option `ref.zero` that manipulate the predictions from a model (e.g., Cox regression) so that the predicted value is 0 when the X-variable is at its reference value. From the help of the function:

> subtract a constant from X beta before plotting so that the reference value of the ‘x’-variable > yields ‘y=0’."

This function also manipulates the standard errors so that the confidence band is 0 at the reference value. Example:

```
library(rms)
data(lung)
dd <- datadist(lung) ## Needed by the Predict function
options(datadist="dd")
model <- cph(Surv(time, status) ~ age, data=lung)
pred <- Predict(model, ref.zero=TRUE)
plot(pred)
```

This is the result:

[image]

I'd like to understand the manipulation done: how is this constant obtained? How is the confidence band calculated after substraction of the constant?

Comment: You may inspect the code of the plot method: `rms:::plot.Predict`

Comment: I think this might be a more appropriate question for cross validated